# Issues with executing wp_ajax_(action)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, action

```
 function delete_product(id)
    {
        alert(id);
        $.post('ajax.php', {action:'remove_product_action'}, function(result){
           alert('success'); 
        });

    }
```

When I call the above function, I get the 'id' value in alert and 'success' as well, but there is no response from the wp_ajax_(action). The PHP code is as follows:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_remove_product_action','remove_product');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_product_action','remove_product');

function remove_product()
{
    header('Location:login.php');
    echo "<script>alert('1');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have header(...); in your ajax callback? Remove this. Also echo "<script>" looks like a really bad idea. Just return a string or json and then proceed with the result.

Comment: From the documentation: "All WordPress Ajax requests must be sent to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php." For more details: [Developer Handbook - Ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/).

Comment: Are you sure that the `ajax.php` url working properly?

Comment: The correct path is not `ajax.php` but rather `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Actually, I'm not directly coding in Wordpress, I have just included wpcore in my PHP project to use wpdb queries. I am very sure that ajax.php is at proper location and working fine, as I have configured its location in another 'config.php' file. Please help me out if you have any other idea.

Comment: @Blackbam header and <script> is used only to check whether the function works properly or not, once this issue is resolved, I'll put the code as per the need.